# Nhibernate wrapper query

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, hibernate-criteria, correlated-subquery

I want to achieve following thing in Nhibernate, I have SQL query like this

```
select 
  rs.firstname, rs.lastname, COUNT(rs.id)
from 
  (select firstname, lastname, (select name from users where userid = '12345') as id 
     from person p) rs
group by rs.firstname, rs.lastname
```

How can i achieve this in Nhibernate? Any pointers will help.

Comment: @gdoron This is slightly unfair. This is a perfectly valid question and I would not find an answer to this on Google. OP I have given you a +1 to restore the balance.

Comment: so google this `session.CreateSqlQuery nhibernate`

Comment: @Rippo. You can't get an answer how to convert sql query to NHibernate without show the classes.

Comment: @gdoron - Still a little unfair, as the OP probably does not know the phrase `CreateSQlQuery`. Without this bit of knowledge they are highly unlikely to find out how.

Comment: @Rippo. I know it, but I can't answer this question! what are the classes, mapping files?

Comment: @Rippo I'll have to agree with gdoron. The question shows no effort - reading the docs, explaining the problem, the domain, etc. It's one of those "please do everything for me, I don't want to think" questions.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon I take it you read the first comment that has now been deleted from gdoron

Comment: @Rippo I did not; only saw the downvote and close request, and assumed your response was related. Scratch my first sentence if it doesn't make sense, but I still stand by the second one. This is not a good question for the site.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon I agree, but sometimes people just need a little extra help and if I have a spare 5 mins I don't mind. The question is a bit sparse and we need quite a bit more info, especially now I have seen the OP comment on my answer!

Answer (score 2):

@gdoron is partially correct, You have two options, a) use `Session.CreateSqlQuery` or b) use a named query which IMO is probably your best option.

In your XML mappings:-

```
<sql-query name="GetNameAndCount">
<![CDATA[
select 
  rs.Firstname, rs.Lastname, COUNT(rs.id) CountOf
from 
  (select firstname, lastname, (select name from users where userid = :id) as id 
     from person p) rs
group by rs.firstname, rs.lastname 
]]>
</sql-query>
```

and to retreive the data

```
var results = Session
  .GetNamedQuery("GetNameAndCount")
  .SetInt32("id", id)
  .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(NameCountDto)));

return results.List<NameCountDto>();
```

and your DTO would look like

```
class NameCountDto {
  public virtual string Firstname { get; set;}
  public virtual string Lastname { get; set;}
  public virtual int CountOf { get; set;}
}
```

Be warned the column names in your query and your property names case must match.

You could also most likely solve this using HQL, Criteria or QueryOver (I think*) but we would need to see your class and mappings.

Comment: Hi Rippo,

Thanks for replying, however in my case scenario is bit more complicated. As I have mentioned in my query, I have used count as aggregation however it can be anything other than just count. The inner query will be more complicated than the one posted in my previous post Also this is for reporting purpose so we do not want to create separate DTOs... 

Any other solution comes to your mind other than using HQL ?

Comment: You see, You can't answer a question without context. +1 though for the effort!